# How to make graphite from wood/charcoal

Tags: organic-chemistry

Would be very grateful if someone had the answer or can point me in a direction. I've searched a lot but didn't find it yet. It could benefit others as well.

I do not have a high tech lab, but I can invest, would prefer methods that don't require above \$100 or \$300, but am open to it. I can build a furnace and weld.

Edit: As I don't have 50 rep points to reply, I will answer here to comments the first comment as to what use I need it for;
It is for water Nanofiltration of 1 micron or lower ,and secondly batteries making.
--- Second comment; thanx alot for the document, I will check it and tell you about it.

Comment: What do you want to use the graphite for? the use you intend for it can really change the method used for the synthesis

Comment: graphitization of carbon materials occurs well above above 2500 celsium, so I suspect there is no pragmatic means to do so. Graphite is available online, though.

Comment: @permeakra never heard of microwave ovens? lasers maybe? this technology can reach far above 2500 "celsium", those who buy online can't call themselves physicists

Answer (score 3):

There was a [method](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US568323.pdf) patented in 1896 whose claims would seem to meet your requirements.  Even with your restricted budget, used laboratory equipment companies can probably provide you what you need.

An excerpt from the patent states:

> "My invention relates to the production of graphite from any of the
>   cheap and common forms of carbonaceous materials, such as mineral
>   coal, coke, charcoal, gas-carbon, and carbids and the like; and it has
>   for its object to provide a process or method of cheaply and
>   practically producing pure graphite..."

The reagents used are common, cheap and readily available.  The patent states that:

> "[the mixture is] composed of powdered coke, sand, salt, and sawdust,
>   the coke forming about fifty per cent., by weight, of the mixture, and
>   these materials are thoroughly mixed and introduced into the electric
>   furnace..."

The key issue for you will be designing the high-temperature inductively heated furnace, though the patent describes this thoroughly, including diagrams.

The availability of used equipment to fashion the device as stated is of course uncertain, and you will have to be creative with what is available.  I would start my search with [LabX](http://www.labx.com/), with whom I have no affiliation whatsoever.  I hope this does "point you in the right direction", and Good luck!

Comment: so, what about the professor Roop Mahajan who creates graphene from coal by grinding coal to coarse powder which is later ball-milled to nano-sized particles which later reacted with nitric acid to convert it into graphene oxide ,which are later reduced to pure graphene ? you just need to press it in order to make graphite (ACS Appl. Nano Mater. 2023, 6, 15, 14594–14608)